# submit of form to different action page jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, ajaxform

Well I am not able to send form multiple times. The initial part of the code of AjaxForm is working fine whereas the FormData is not working. Instead it send the data in the url without the page like
*index.php?photos[]=&username=dfdfdf*. The Earlier part is used for image storage and second part is used for user data storage. My requirement is to use single form to send data to different table in database. When the user click submit the data is stored in the data table and the uploaded image also gets updated with that user ID.
Hope You will solve the problem!

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("db.php");
$str = "select * from fileupload order by id DESC";
$res = mysql_query($str);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>


<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function() { 
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            url : 'ajaxImageUpload.php',
            target: '#preview', 
            beforeSubmit:function(){ 

                console.log('ttest');
                $("#imageloadstatus").show();
                $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
            }, 
            success:function(){ 
                console.log('test');
                $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                $("#imageloadbutton").show();
            }, 
            error:function(){ 
                console.log('xtest');
                $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                $("#imageloadbutton").show();
            } }).submit();


    });

    $(".del-pic").live("click", function(){
        var sel1 = $(this).closest('.imgList');
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post("deleteimage.php", {
            del_id : del_id
        },
               function(data, txtStatus) {
                   sel1.fadeOut('slow', function()
                                {
                                    sel1.remove();
                                });
               });
    });

    $("#uploadTrigger").click(function(){
        $("#photoimg").click();
    });

    $("#upbutton").live("click", function(){
        $("#imageform").bind('submit',function(e){
            if(window.FormData !== undefined)  // for HTML5 browsers
            {
                var formdata = new FormData(this);

                $.post({
                    url : "insertuser.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : formdata,
                    mimeType : "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType : false,
                    cache : false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data, txtstatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function(data, txtstatus, errorthrown)
                    {
                        alert('error');
                    }

                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert('HTML5 not supporting in your browser');  
            }

        });
    });
}); 
</script>

<style> 
#preview
{
color:#cc0000;
font-size:12px;
background: #066;
}
.imgList 
{
max-height:100px;
margin-left:10px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;    
float:left;
}
.hidden
{
    display: none;  
}
#uploadTrigger
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: #777;
    color: #fff;
    width:75px; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family:arial;

}
.del-pic
{
    background-image:url(../../Krishna/images2/closebox.png);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    margin:-10px 0 0 85px;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>

<div id='preview' style="">
<?
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
     echo "<div class='imgList'><div class='del-pic' id='".$row['id']."'></div><img src='".$row['filename']."' width='100px' height='100px' ></div>";   
    }
?>
</div>

<form id="imageform" name="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="clear:both">
<div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
<div id='imageloadbutton'>
<div id="uploadTrigger">Add Photo</div>
<input type="file" name="photos[]" id="photoimg" class="hidden" multiple="true" />

<input name="username" type="text" id="username" />

<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upbutton" />
</div>
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `.live` and `.die`, they were deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. Use `.on` and `.off`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the comment! I realize it but still I am talking about FormData.

Comment: You're creating the `FormData` object, but you never add anything to it.

Comment: It's almost never right to bind one event handler inside another event handler. The `#imageform submit` handler shouldn't be inside the `#upbutton click` handler.

Comment: Can you explain it? I am new to this !!, I have used this so it attaches all the elements of form in it!

Comment: As you said earlier I removed the #upbutton click handler!

Comment: Never mind, I didn't notice that you gave an argument to `new FormData()`, which makes it automatically pick up all the fields from the form.

Comment: okay, Can you find any error in FormData? It isn't working properly